# How to Set Document Orientation (for All Pages) in MigraDoc Library?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, migradoc

I'm using [MigraDoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) to programatically generate a PDF file with text, images and tables.

I need to set `Document` **Orientation** (for all pages) in the document object to `Landscape`.

So I tried the following.

```
document.DefaultPageSetup.Orientation = Orientation.Landscape;
```

But I get the following debug assertion error.

```
---------------------------
Assertion Failed: Abort=Quit, Retry=Debug, Ignore=Continue
---------------------------

DefaultPageSetup must not be modified
```

If I click **Ignore**, it goes through and the `Orientation` is indeed `Landscape`.

However, I want to make sure I am doing this the right way.

So the question is, how do I set the document orientation for all pages in a `Document` using the MigraDoc library?

Here's the rest of the code (so it helps you get the context)

```
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel;

namespace MyNamespace.PdfReports
{
    class Documents
    {
        public static Document CreateDocument()
        {
            // Create a new MigraDoc document
            Document document = new Document();
            document.Info.Title = "The Title";
            document.Info.Subject = "The Subject";
            document.Info.Author = "Shiva";
            document.DefaultPageSetup.Orientation = Orientation.Landscape;
```

Many thanks!
-Shiva

#### UPDATE:

**SOLUTION:** Here's the working code, based on [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1015447/thomash)' answer below (for the benefit of others who maybe looking for this solution).

```
// Create a new MigraDoc document
Document document = new Document();
//...
//......
PageSetup pageSetup = document.DefaultPageSetup.Clone();
// set orientation
pageSetup.Orientation = Orientation.Landscape;
// ... set other page setting you want here...
```

Comment: DefaultPageSetup applies to MigraDoc. Actually this is a MigraDoc question, not a PDFsharp question.

Comment: Hi, Shiva, you just solved my problem for me. Thanks for that :-) Although your solution didn't contain the information that you need to assign the modified pageSetup to the section object. But anyways: thank you :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assign `DefaultPageSetup.Clone()` to the `PageFormat` of your section and modify that.

Then you modify a copy of the default settings and no assertion will fail.

With your approach, all documents would default to landscape - not just the document you set it for.

This answer applies to <kbd>MigraDoc</kbd> only as only <kbd>MigraDoc</kbd> uses `DefaultPageSetup`.

See [this post in the PDFsharp forum](http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=7063#p7063) where `Clone()` is used to create a copy of the `DefaultPageSetup`:

Comment: Thanks Thomas! Based on your answer and the link, I fixed the code to clone the DefaultPageSetup and apply the setting on that. Updated my question with the code also.