# MigraDoc + PDFsharp to generate Horizontal PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, horizontalscrollview, pdfsharp, migradoc

I am using MigraDoc + PDFsharp for generating a PDF (Salary slip). The PDF that is generated is by default vertical. (A4 - vertical).

I want it to be generated as Horizontal.
What changes do I need to do?

[currently I'm able to get this PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVRhT.png)

[Sample image of expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPZdx.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Set Document Orientation (for All Pages) in MigraDoc Library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674363/how-to-set-document-orientation-for-all-pages-in-migradoc-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to know how to set page format to landscape.

```
PageSetup pageSetup = document.DefaultPageSetup.Clone();
// set orientation
pageSetup.Orientation = Orientation.Landscape;
// ... set other page setting you want here...
```

Assign that PageSetup to your section.

See also:
[How to Set Document Orientation (for All Pages) in MigraDoc Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674363/how-to-set-document-orientation-for-all-pages-in-migradoc-library)

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this old question while searching for a method to achieve this without MigraDoc... If you want to use just PdfSharp (without MigraDoc) you cloud do the following:

```cs
var document = new PdfDocument();
var page = document.AddPage();
// Set the page orientation to landscape
page.Orientation = PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Landscape;
```